# ASP.NET Core 2.1 - multiple appSettings with registration

Tags: asp.net-core

besides the normal appsettings.config file, I have an additional one, which looks like this:

```
{
...
"region": "eu",
...
}
```

I'm trying to figure out how to register them to be available with `IOptions` injection - the main issue here is that, those settings cannot be placed within a section (don't ask why), like

```
{
...
"mySection": {
      "region": "eu",
   }
...
}
```

and in that case I cannot register the strongly-typed POCO configuration:

```
services.Configure<mySettings>(Configuration.GetSection("mySection"));
```

do you know how to fix it ?

Comment: What do you mean by `an additional one`? Do you have a different `appsettings.json` file or you add the content in the existing `appsettings.json`? What is the defination for `mySettings`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the action overload of `Configure<T>`:

```
services.Configure<mySettings>(c => {
    c.Region = Configuration["region"]
    // etc.
});
```